Leftover fallen world technologies
My fantasy novels are set in a world that reached WWI era technology in the distant past, but used magic in place of electricity and combustions. For complicated reasons, the magic stopped working, and a lot of that advanced technology stopped working as well and they reverted to a more medieval level of technology.
However, I want this world to have remnants of that old world. They have germ theory, and have a good understanding of how to treat wounds and the sick. They have the printing press. They have concrete, gliders, hot air balloons, etc. In some places, most people can read, value education, and there are newspapers. Primitive cameras exist. There are even some proto republican and capitalist elements present, though the world is still dominated by monarchy.
They DON'T have gunpowder.
I really like this sort of setting, but I'm having a lot of trouble trying to imagine the implications of all these futuristic technologies and ideas being present in a more or less medieval setting. Can they make hypodermic needles? Would penicillin and other antibiotics be too impractical to make at a large scale? Would it be possible for them to make large scale gliders that can transport troops across enemy lines?
A big inspiration for this setting was SM Stirlings Emberverse series, as it did something very similar, though the worlds are still quite different.
Any suggestions on how to make this setting more realistic or interesting would be greatly appreciated.

Please take the tour and see how this site works.  There is a firm rule of one question per post, where you are asking 3 questions and then requesting general suggestions, ie brainstorming (which is also a close reason).  Please narrow your question down to a single question, without invalidating the existing answer/s.

Your society would basically be very much like the Russian Empire during the 18th and 19th centuries.


"They have the printing press."
As I have explained elsewhere, the printing press is not what Gutenberg invented. The printing press had been known for many centuries in China; even in Europe woodcut prints were being made in the early 1400s or thereabouts. It is perfectly fine to have printing presses in a medieval context, as, in actual history, they actually did have in the Far East.

"They have concrete."
The Romans had used concrete on a large scale a full thousand years before the Middle Ages, so that there is nothin special about having concrete in a medieval setting.

"There are even some proto republican and capitalist elements present..."
The Republic of Venice was a major power in the second half of the Middle Ages, so that there is nothing special about having republics in a medieval context. Oh, and the Republic of Venice is just an example; there were quite a few others.
As for capitalist elements, there has never ever been a successful civilization without capitalist elements. All attempts to create one failed abysmally. Yes, they had powerful capitalist elements in the Middle Ages.

"... although the world is still dominated by monarchy."
That's funny, because the medieval European world was definitely not dominated by monarchy. Sure there were kings, but they had limited power, quite often very limited power. In Europe, absolute monarchy is an Early Modern thing, which would have been abhorrent to any rightful thinking medieval person.

"Can they make hypodermic needles?"
If you are serious about them having a "medieval level of technology", then no, not really; at least not something we would recognize as a hypodermic needle as opposed to a trocar.

"Would penicillin and other antibiotics be too impractical to make at a large scale?"
If you are serious about them having a "medieval level of technology", then penicillin and other antibiotics would be completely impractical to make at any scale. Chemistry is technology. Stainless steel is technology. Standardized units of measurement are technology.

"Would it be possible for them to make large scale gliders that can transport troops across enemy lines?"
One glider, sure. Two gliders, maybe. Three gliders, only a very rich king. More than three, no, not really. A very rich European medieval king was not rich at all by modern standards; think of a very rich European medieval king as being rich enough to employ a few hundred men-at-arms, nothing more fancy than that.
Oh, and once they built their one or two gliders, what do they do with them? With a medieval level of technology they do not have steam engines, so they cannot launch the gliders... Yes, a glider can take off in good conditions by rolling downhill on a favorable slope which happens to end above a deep cliff, but that's not going to help much with carrying troops above enemy lines.
Oh, and a very large glider, such as the famous British Horsa can carry maybe two dozen soldiers. One or two such gliders won't make much of a difference.


Finally, the major difficulty is that with a medieval level of technology the population level is by necessity quite low, and the vast majority of the population is busy working in agriculture; which means that they are not available for anything else.
Major differences between a world with a medieval level of technology and the modern world:

Textiles are very expensive, because medieval level of technology. Good clothes are expensive enough to be mentioned in wills.

Overland transportation of heavy items is not practical at all. Yes, if you are emperor of Rome you can arrange for an Egyptian obelisk to be transported overland on a distance of a few dozen miles, one time in your reign. Routinely transporting overland tonnes of wheat or fish or iron or whatever over a distance of more than a few dozen miles, forget about it.

Illumination at night is a biggg problem with no real practical solution. Public illumination of streets is completely impractical, except maybe in the richest parts of a very few very rich cities.

Centralized government of a large country is a pipe dream. Moving any kind of force from one end of France to the other end takes two months or so. A fast courier can bring news from Marseilles to Paris in maybe two weeks; two weeks to respond back, and when your answer comes you are one month behind the events. This is why you have all those dukes and counts and so on to govern the provinces for you.



Frame Challenge
They havent gone back to Medieval technology.
So - if Electricity and Combustion were fuelled (heh) by Magic - okay, fair enough - that is going to be a major disruption.
However, both of those are only really useful for advanced Tech if you have precision engineering Things like Lathes, Micrometers, Milling machines - all that were invented and standardized in the Industrial Revolution - you still have those.
Now - for the sake of argument - lets say that all the heavy machinery that would have been Steam driven is now longer operable due to now input power - fair enough - but the ability to make repeatable precision parts and the knowledge of how to do that still exists.
This factor alone means that they cant regress further back than the early 1800s. Those machines would likely be converted to use water wheels (which had been used in industry all the way back to the Roman era - and specifically were used for Grain Milling and metal work in the 1300s)
So - whilst the removal of combustion engines and electricity powered by Magic is a massive hinderance - those only work if you have precision, repeatable engineering - which in-of-itself does not require magic - therefore I do not believe that absent some other factors or events that the premise is reasonable.

Thanks you guys. I think a point of clarification would be that the same catastrophe that caused this worlds magic to cease working also caused the collapse of all the worlds nations and the death of most of its population. This world was essentially ruled by two large opposing blocks who opposed each other cold war style. One was entirely destroyed, and the other was forced to abandon its homeland. So it's a post apocalypses environment as well, and so a lot of the knowledge they had (but not all) was lost.
